Why Can't We Directly Sample Realizations from a Wiener Process Using Its Joint Gaussian Distribution?
I am trying to understand the relationship between sampling from the joint distribution of a Wiener process and the process's defining properties. Here's what I know:

The Wiener process $W_t$ is defined as a Gaussian process with:
$$
   W_0 = 0, \quad W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t), \quad \text{and} \quad \mathrm{Cov}(W_t, W_s) = \min(t, s).
   $$
Additionally, it has independent increments, meaning:
$$
   W_{t+\Delta t} - W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Delta t),
   $$
and this increment is independent of $W_t$.

The joint distribution of $W_t$ at any finite set of time points $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n $ is multivariate Gaussian with covariance matrix:
$$
   K_{ij} = \min(t_i, t_j).
   $$
This covariance structure encodes all dependencies between time points.

Given the above, one should theoretically be able to sample directly from the multivariate Gaussian joint distribution $ \mathcal{N}(0, K) $ to obtain a realization of the process at those times.


Here’s my confusion:

Why does directly sampling from $ \mathcal{N}(0, K) $ not fully respect the Wiener process definition? Specifically, doesn't the joint distribution already account for all dependencies, including the independent increment property?

If the joint distribution is correct, what prevents it from enforcing the incremental structure? For example, the Wiener process requires that:
$$
  W_{t+\Delta t} - W_t \quad \text{is independent of} \quad W_t,
  $$
but isn’t this already encoded in $ K $?

Why can't the Wiener process support direct sampling like a Gaussian process? Gaussian processes allow sampling a complete realization from their covariance structure in one step without iterative sampling.


I suspect this has to do with the difference between "realizations of a process" and the specific construction of the Wiener process, but I’m struggling to understand why. Could someone clarify the distinction and explain why iterative sampling is essential for Wiener processes, even when the joint distribution is known?

If you simply want to sample W at a discrete set of time points, what led you to think you couldn't just do that? That is - what led you to think there was an issue?

@Glen_b This is not a scientific answer, but I haven't seen anyone care about the joint distribution in the Weiner process. However, in the Gaussian process, they do that. So, my conclusion was it's gotta be a catch I don't understand.

The 'catch' is there's a much simpler way to do it, which is why in practice you wouldn't typically do it that way.

@Glen_b Interesting. 1. How come an iterative method that has $O(n)$ time complexity be more efficient than doing at once. 2. Why don't they sample from Gaussian process like they do for Weiner process then?

with 1, by what method are you planning to "sample directly from a multivariate Gaussian"? Note that $K$ is an $n\times n$ matrix so most calculations that refer to its elements will be at least $O(n^2)$. E.g. if you calculate a Cholesky decomposition of $K$, you're in for $O(n^3)$. With some cleverness you might be able to get to $O(n^2)$ perhaps, but if its any less direct than a matrix decomposition of $K$, it might be harder to maintain that its any more direct than sampling the increments (which could be rewritten in matrix terms, in which case it's a more efficient way of computing that)

On question 2, if you accept that the denial of the premise (i.e. if you accept that you can in fact "sample directly from a multivariate Gaussian" but will generally be better to choose to do something else instead), that particular issue might be a useful reframing of the original question you posted. On the other hand, if you don't accept it, leave the question as is, and someone (possibly me) can address the premise in an answer.

hi rando: the covariance of two brownian motions being the min(s,t) cannot be preserved by generating a multivariate gaussian. So, the covariance of two BM's OVER TIME, is not implied by the multivariate gaussian. That and the independent increments property has to be enforced. If you have a covariance matrix for the multivariate gaussian, that covariance is the  between two elements in the vector. That's not the covariance of the two brownian motions.

It's kind of like BM implies multivariate gaussian but multivariate gaussian doesn't imply BM. you need more. Nothing in the specification of the covariance matrix results in independent increments nor cov(B_s, B_t) = min(s,t). The standard multivariate gaussian covariance matrix can't capture movement over time and the BM moves over infinitesmal units of time and has properties with respect to that movement.

@mlofton my understanding that the joint should model all dependencies otherwise the model is wrong. 2. Glen_b noted that we can use the joint to sample from but it is more efficient to use the iterative method.

rondo: I'm probably not explaining it very well but if you look at any decent-level brownian motion text ( shilling, wiersema ), and read carefully through the respective  "construction of brownian motion" section, you will see why what you are saying won't work. that's probably the only way to really see it.

I know glen_b knows his stuff ( FOR SURE ) but all generating the gaussians does is give you a sample of gaussians. There is a time ordering that needs to be respected and the sample won't capure that. Think of the random walk : $x_t = x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$. As $t$ gets finer and finer and finer and finer, you've got an infinitismally additive process that is called brownian motion in the limit. The gaussian sample can't do that AFAIK.

I don't mean to sound like "I'm right" and "your wrong". If anyone thinks I'm wrong ( which could very well be the case, it's happened before ), I don't mind. But if you can explain where I'm going wrong, it's appreciated. I thought I understood BM ( finally ) but maybe I don't !!!!!!!!

@mlofton I'm here to learn. I'm not in a place to prove anyone wrong as I'm no expert on this topic. Glen_b mentioned in his comment: "If you simply want to sample W at a discrete set of time points," so I assume his statement of sampling from the joint is constrained by a discrete set of time points. Now, when going to a very small $\epsilon$ then, the joint will need a huge amount of memory, which renders it impractical.

rondo: think of it this way: For a specific, $t$, the observations is gaussian and you could generate a gaussian for that $t$. But the process is continuous. So, you'd have to do that over all t and make it additive for all t. I gotta go but I'll check out the comments later.

I agree with you. Just here to learn also. Hopefully glen_b can explain his argument in more detail or give a reference. Talk later and no offense intended. It's a very good question and made me think a lot.

I read Glen_b's first comment again along with your question and he says "if you simply want to sample W at a discrete set of time points". So, I think what's he saying is generate a BM for a specifically FIXED t.  That's different than generating a BM over time. So, I most likely made a mistake in interpreting your question. Glen_b doesn't mean generate a BM. He means, chose a time $t$ and then generate points at that time $t$.

Those points will have the covariance representation of the joint distribution but they won't satisfy anything about min(s,t) or independent increments because t is FIXED.  For one to satisfy the cov(s,t) = min(s,t) or independent increments, one needs to generate the actual process. So, my mistake for interpreting question incorrectly.
